# Changing Color Ramp in ArcGIS Online Heatmap?

Tags: arcgis-online, heat-map, color-ramp

I have a series of points that are being visualized as a heatmap in ArcGIS Online. The issue is that my team does not particularly like any of the 4 default color ramps offered by ESRI in the "symbols" tab (see the image).

[image]

Is it possible to alter these color ramps without requiring additional resources--ArcGIS for Server/ etc? (I'm aware of how to do it in [ESRI leaflet](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/styling-heatmaps.html)). It just seems strange that there would be such a limited palette in AGOL.

Comment: I dont think so, unless you want to make use of the ArcGIS Javascript API where you have control over these colors https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/heatmaprenderer-amd.html

Comment: do you have arc desktop?  you can create the heatmap in desktop with whatever color scheme you wish and publish it, then import the layer from the web and it will have the color scheme you picked earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not been able to use either of the workarounds suggested in the comments I think you may need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) to have ArcGIS Online's palette increased.